How Authorization with Blazor web app works?
I created a blazor web app auto render mode project with individual accounts, in the PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider it only picks up one role :
var role = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType)?.Value; 
But I have a user with two roles, how come both authorizeView are appearing in my application in the following code when I'm only getting one in PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider?
Shouldn't AuthorizeView only appear for one of the roles?
<AuthorizeView Roles=‘@Roles.Admin’>
    <br />
    <h2>You are Admin!</h2>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Roles=‘@Roles.User’>
    <br />
    <h2>You are User!</h2>
</AuthorizeView>

Can someone explain me this.

.FindFirst() only takes the first record for that claim, hence you should use .FindAll() to list all the claims.
var getRoleClaims = principal.FindAll(options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType);

foreach (var claim in getRoleClaims) {
    var roleName = claim.Value;
}

Screenshot for user with "Admin" role


That's not really my question.I have an user with admin and user roles. I want to know why, since I only have one role because of FindFirst and I only store it in the claim, why when I run the application both authorizeView are visible, since I only have the admin role stored in the claim, for example. Shouldn't only the Admin authorizeView appear?

@FranciscoFernandes By default the claims provider adds all the user's roles. Even though you are using FindFirst(), it is just pulling the claim from a list of claims that have already been registered. In your case, you're pulling User, but both User and Admin already exists in claims.

ah ok, so by default the claims provider adds all the user roles, putting FindFirst or FindAll isn't important because it already has them by default? or should I do FindAll anyway or can I just delete ´var role = main.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType)?.Value;` and do nothing, since it's doing it by default?

@FranciscoFernandes yes, all the claims is already registered there. What FindFirst or FindAll does is just read the data. If you really want to modify claims on login, you can refer to claims transformer; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-8.0

OK, thanks for the explanation.
